# Literal Assignment in Java

Tags: java, double, literals

what's the difference in defining

```
double example = 23.1d
```

or

```
double example = 23.1
```

Why long, float and double can end with  l,  f,  d?

Comment: Some people may think the *d* suffix is useless. But it isn't. For example *123* is int and *123d* is double.

Answer (score 20):

There is no difference between `double example = 23.1d;` and `double example = 23.1;` because a floating point literal without a *type suffix* is always interpreted as a double.

The type suffixes are necessary in order to avoid ambiguities in certain scenarios.

For example, java supports method overloading.  This means that you can have `void x( float f );` and `void x( double d );`  Both methods are called `x`; which one will be selected depends on the type that you pass; if you pass a variable which is already known to be either float or double, things are clear; but if you want to pass a literal, like this: `x( 5 );` then you have to be able to specify whether you mean this 5 to be a float or a double, so as to select the right method.

There are a few other very nuanced situations where the type of the literal matters.  For example, the following code:

```
System.out.println( "" + (2/3.3333) );
System.out.println( "" + (2/3.3333f) );
```

Yields the following output:

```
0.6000060000600006
0.600006
```

...because the first number is a double, while the second number is a float.

Similar disambiguation concerns make the "L" type suffix necessary for long integer literals.

Answer (score 1):

23.1d (or just 23.1, since double is the default) is a different number than 23.1f. Since 23.1 cannot be exactly represented, 23.1f is the closest float to 23.1, and has only about 6 significant figures. As a double, 23.1 will have about 16 significant figures and can therefore get a bit closer to the actual value.

Note that

```
double example = 23.1f;
```

is equivalent to

```
float f = 23.1f;
double example = (double)f;
```

Comment: Thanks so much,  why a double cannot be exactly represented?

Comment: @themagiciant95 because a double has finite precision.