# Test if value of double is less than maximum value of an int

Tags: java, int, double

Assume that `d` is a `double` variable. Write an if statement that assigns d to the `int` variable `i` if the value in `d` is not larger than the maximum value for an `int`.

The method below is my attempt at this problem:

```
public static void assignInt(double d)
{
  int i = 0;
  if(d < Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    i =  (int)d;
  System.out.print(i);
}
```

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` holds `2147483647`. I am assuming this is the maximum value an `int` can hold? With this assumption in mind, I attempt to call `assingDoubleToInt()` three times:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  assignDoubleToInt(2147483646); //One less than the maximum value an int can hold
  assignDoubleToInt(2147483647); //The maximum value an int can hold
  assignDoubleToInt(2147483648);//One greater than the maximum value an int can hold. Causes error and does not run.
}
```

The first two calls output:

```
2147483646
0
```

And the third call, `assignDoubleToInt(2147483648);`, throws `"The literal 2147483648 of type int is out of range."`  Isn't the comparison `2147483648 < 2147483647` here? Why is `i` being assigned the value if the comparison should evaluate to `false`?

Using the comparison `d < Integer.MAX_VALUE` is not the proper way to do this. How can I test whether a `double` variable can fit in an `int` variable?

Comment: Use `2147483648.0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Literal Assignment in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777836/literal-assignment-in-java)

Comment: *"if the value in `d` is **not larger than** the maximum value for an `int`"* Note that "not larger than" is not the same as "less than". What if the value is **equal to** the maximum value for an `int`? The code should be `if (d <= Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

Comment: I don't think it actually *throws* anything, I think that's a compiler error, yes?  Could also use `2147483648L`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Integer.MAX_VALUE` holds `2147483647`. I am assuming this is the maximum value an int can hold?

Yes.

> throws `"The literal 2147483648 of type int is out of range."`

You can't create an `int` literal representing a number outside of the `int` range, so `2147483647` is legal but `2147483648` is not.  If you want a larger integer literal, use a long literal, with the letter L appended: `2147483648L`, or a double literal with a decimal point (or D appended): `2147483648.0` (or `2147483648D`).

> is not the proper way to do this.

The comparison `d < Integer.MAX_VALUE` is legal <s>and correct</s>, because `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will be widened to a `double` for the comparison, and a `double` can be (much) larger in value than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  You just need to make sure you can pass the proper value in as detailed above.

(As noted in a comment above, it should be `d <= Integer.MAX_VALUE`, with `<=`.)

Answer (score 1):

The int range issue is because you have an int literal. Use a double literal by postfixing 'd':

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    assignDoubleToInt(2147483646); // One less than the maximum value an int can hold
    assignDoubleToInt(2147483647); // The maximum value an int can hold
    assignDoubleToInt(2147483648d);// One greater than the maximum value an int can hold. Causes error and does not
                                  // run.
}
```

I believe your equality test should be `<=`, also: "if the value in d is not larger than the maximum value for an int" - so if it is EQUAL to the maximum value for an int, it's valid:

```
public static void assignDoubleToInt(double d) {
    int i = 0;
    if (d <= Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        i = (int) d;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```